# Lua Arguments in AwesomeWM

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I've been at this for a long time now. The [AwesomeWM API](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/) doesn't document this well enough. I'm just confused as to how I am supposed to put arguments in this:

```
local cal = awful.widget.calendar_popup.month()
```

The documents say that arguments go inside the brackets. I have tried many things but nothing worked. Just how are [these arguments](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/awful.widget.calendar_popup.html#awful.widget.calendar_popup.month) supposed to go in the brackets? I have tried doing something like:

```lua
    local cal = awful.widget.calendar_popup.month({
           position = "tc",
           bg = "#19191999",
           other values etc etc
    })
cal:attach( mytextclock)
```

and a variety of other things but nothing worked. What's the correct way?

**EDIT:** Found out the correct way to do this is this:

```lua
local cal = awful.widget.calendar_popup.month({
    style_month = {
       bg_color = "#19191999",
       fg_color = "#ffffff"
    },
})

cal:attach( mytextclock, "tc" )
```

keep in mind the position of the widget has to remain in the attached widget. Hence "tc".

Comment: this should be ok, what do you mean with "nothing worked"?

Comment: It had no changes at all. Nothing changed. Any argument I'd put inside the brackets would simply have no effect. Calling it using `cal:attach(mytextclock)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Found out the correct way to do this is this:

```lua
local cal = awful.widget.calendar_popup.month({
    style_month = {
       bg_color = "#19191999",
       fg_color = "#ffffff"
    },
})

cal:attach( mytextclock, "tc" )
```

keep in mind the position of the widget has to remain in the attached widget. Hence "tc".